# How create List<Float>?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a list of float values, but it seems it's not right this way :
EDIT:

```
public Supervisory() {
    this.analogs = new ArrayList<Float>();
}

public void active() {
    try {
        for (ObjectIdentifier oi : ois) {

            if (oi.getObjectType().intValue() == 2){
                analogs.add(new Float(10));
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ioe.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

My last code it was just a snippet to give the idea of my problem.

What's wrong with this implementation ?

Comment: Is this an exact snippet from your code?

Comment: where is the decleration and where is the initialization ? What's the error?

Comment: Also, why are all the answers saying to call the lines in a method?  Why not in the constructor?

Comment: @brano  List is an interface, and cannot be instantiated.

Comment: Question was edited, so what's the problem now? Where the exception is thrown? in Which line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put your code inside a method, it cannot just float around in the class:

```
public class MyClass {
   private List<Float> analogs;

   public void X() {
       this.analogs = new ArrayList<Float>();
       analogs.add(new Float(10));
   }
}
```

Or in a constructor:

```
public class MyClass {
   private List<Float> analogs;

   public MyClass() {
       this.analogs = new ArrayList<Float>();
       analogs.add(new Float(10));
   }
}
```

Comment: But why I cannot initialize the 'analogs' attribute in the constructor ?

Answer (score 3):

place these two lines into a method

```
this.analogs = new ArrayList<Float>();
analogs.add(new Float(10));
```

Your `analogs` is a field of the class and these lines are coming after `analogs`'s declaration.